# PHP PDO Login system not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following files on my server:

**mysql.php**

```
   <?php
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PWD','root');
define('DB_DATABASE','portaldaturma');

try{
$pdo = new PDO(DB_DRIVER . ':host' . DB_HOST . ';dbname='. DB_DATABASE, DB_USER, DB_PWD);
if($pdo){
    echo "Conexao realizada com sucesso!";
} else{
    echo "Erro na conexão.";
    }
} catch (PDOException $exc){
echo "Problemas na conexão!";
echo $exc->getMessage();
}

?>
```

**auth.php**

```
    <?PHP
include('mysql.php'); 


$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM auth_admin WHERE loginAdmin = ? AND senhaAdmin = ?'); //Query de Busca
$stmt->bindParam(1,$_POST['login'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$_POST['senha'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();
$obj = $stmt->fetchObject();


if($obj){
    $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['login'];
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $_POST['senha'];
    header('location:index.php');


} else{
    echo'Invalid Login/Password';
}
?>
```

My MySQL Server schema:

```
SELECT * FROM auth_admin WHERE loginAdmin = 'robert' AND senhaAdmin = 'paulson';

+---------+------------+------------+---------------+
| idAdmin | loginAdmin | senhaAdmin | nomeAdmin     |
+---------+------------+------------+---------------+
|       2 | robert     | paulson    | RobertPaulson |
+---------+------------+------------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**So what doesn't works?**
Everytime i try to login using a form, the "Invalid Login/Server" message appears, even with only one login/password possible (and i'm pretty sure i'm typing them correctly.)

**Edit**

I've tried hardcoding the SQL with the login and password but it didn't worked!

```
// $login = $_POST['login'];
// $senha = $_POST['senha'];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM auth_admin WHERE loginAdmin = 'patrickmaia' logadm AND senhaAdmin = 'root' "); //Query de Busca
// $stmt->bindParam(':logadm', $login);
// $stmt->bindParam(':senadm', $senha);

$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchObject();
```

The error "Conexao realizada com sucesso! Senha Invalida" continues to appear, the connection works just fine.

Comment: Try saving the password as MD5. (No banco de dados, deve funcionar)

Comment: Are your form parameters correct? Is your form method POST? Is your statement causing an error? Does your DB user have access? (I guess root does). What if you hard code the user/pass into the SQL to cut out the form handler from the scenario.  What happens if you take off the WHERE?

Comment: 1 - Yeah, my form parameters are corrent since it used to work before i started moving to PDO.
2 - Yes, POST.
3 - No errors, only the messages in the "else" condition.
4 - Yes, it has access. 
5 - Actually that was a great ideia! I've tried hardcoding the SQL like you said and the error keeps appearing, so the problem isn't in the query. The connection works just fine.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` at the very top of the file. Comment out the `header()` call, so you can see what is going on before the redirect. You want to add `die();` after the header call btw.: header redirects, but does **not** end the execution! which one wants in almost all cases.

Comment: I've tried what you said, nothing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace mysql.php with this code and try:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PWD','ubuntu');
define('DB_DATABASE','ems');

try{  
$pdo = new PDO(DB_DRIVER . ':host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname='. DB_DATABASE, DB_USER, DB_PWD);
if($pdo){
    echo "Conexao realizada com sucesso!";                                      
} else{
    echo "Erro na conexão.";
    }
} catch (PDOException $exc){                                                                    
echo "Problemas na conexão!";
echo $exc->getMessage();
}
?>
```

you are missing `=` after `:host`

Answer (score -1):

You are not checking the error code returned by [`$stmt->execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).  If the statement fails with an [error](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php) (perhaps due to permissions to `SELECT` from that table), then [`$stmt->fetchObject()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php) could very well return `FALSE`.